¿Cómo establecer un valor inicial por defecto en el Dropdown de PrimeReact?
soy nuevo usando React, Typescript y el framework Prime React. Estoy tratando que se inicialice el DropDown con el valor "Rome" pero no hay forma. La idea en realidad es alimentar el DropDown con datos que vienen de una API y establecer el valor inicial por el usuario.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'primereact/dropdown';

export default function UnstyledDemo() {
// Establece el estado inicial a 'RM', que es el código de 'Rome'
const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState('RM');
const cities = [
{ name: 'New York', code: 'NY' },
{ name: 'Rome', code: 'RM' },
{ name: 'London', code: 'LDN' },
{ name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST' },
{ name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS' } ];

return (
<div className="card flex justify-center">
     <Dropdown
       value={selectedCity}
       onChange={(e) => setSelectedCity(e.value)}
       options={cities}
       optionLabel="name"
       placeholder="Select a City"
       className="w-full md:w-14rem"
     />
</div>
);
}

¿Qué se puede hacer para que se me establezca un valor por default?

hola debes cambiar code en tu array cities por value o agregar una propiedad value algo asi:  { name: 'New York', value: 'NY' }, se que ya miraste la documentacion por tu ejemplo pero revisa esto:  Default property name for the optionLabel is label and value for the optionValue. If optionValue is omitted and the object has no value property, the object itself becomes the value of an option. https://primereact.org/dropdown/#basic

Hola Clay. Estuve probando y leyendo la parte que me mencionaste. Me funcionó perfecto. Te agradezco mucho por tu respuesta. Un saludo
